# Ler TXT com AscII Estendido

Tags: c, ascii, printf

Eu fiz o código abaixo para ler um arquivo TXT que contém char estendidos da tabela ascii.

```
int main(void){
printf("%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c \n",205,187,186,187,200,201,205,188);
FILE *ffpOrig=fopen("a.txt", "r");
for(;!feof(ffpOrig);){
  unsigned char ch;
  fread(&ch, sizeof(unsigned char),1, ffpOrig);
  printf("%c",ch);
}
return 0;
}
```

Arquivo a.txt:

> ╔══════════════════════╗
>   ║                      ║
>   ╚══════════════════════╝

Entretanto, para o seguindo printf, ele não apresenta/lê os caracteres corretamente. Ele mostra: ÔòöÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉ.......

PS.: O primeiro printf apresenta corretamente os chars: ═ ╗ ║ ╗ ╚ ╔ ═ ╝.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode tentar ler o arquivo como binário (`ffpOrig=fopen("a.txt", "rb")`) para garantir que os bytes serão lidos como tal (em vez de interpretados como texto).

Comment: Já tentei, e o problema continua.

Comment: O conteúdo do arquivo não tem os caracteres que você está querendo...abra o arquivo num editor que mostre o conteúdo em hexadecimal, para confirmar. (Acho que o editor Notepad++ faz isso).

Comment: Troque por `printf("%i",ch);` e veja se a numeração bate. Provavelmente é o que o José X falou, os caracteres não são os mesmos. Isso que você chama de "caracteres estendidos" na verdade pode ser uma série de codificações completamente diferentes (não existe uma tabela "ASCII Estendido", isso é apenas um conceito). Cada codepage vincula os números acima de 127 a caracteres completamente diferentes. Inclusive o que você mostrou como sendo o "correto" não é absolutamente correto. Só é correto em relação à codepage que você usou como referência.